# Redirect command to gnome-terminal from python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my code which includes few lines:

```
print("python kaldigstserver client.py -r 32000 ",self.filename,file=open("output.txt", "a"))
       with open('output.txt') as my_file:
         file_text = my_file.read()  
         print(file_text)

subprocess.Popen(args=["gnome-terminal", "--working-directory=/home/huma/G-str/kaldi-gstreamer-server"])
```

This opens a terminal when I execute my python program...... But I want to redirect the command from the text file to the terminal.... i.e. output.txt. and execute it automatically.

I don't know how to do that. I tried it with "--command"& "--execute" but it is not working. Is there any way to do it ????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way. The terminal will open another controlling tty and read/write from that. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: can you please tell me the right way to run a command "that locate a file in g-streamer folder  and using that file and an audio send it to a g-streamer server"?????

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. But it sounds like you are running this from a shell already and you just want to run some script? You  can just run it. If you want it to run in the background, start it with an '&' at end of command line.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done one has to use `bash output.text` as the command argument like this `'--command="bash output.text"'`. Note the quotes around the argument are required.

```
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--working-directory=/home/huma/G-str/kaldi-gstreamer-server", '--command="bash output.text"'])
```

If the `output.text` is not in the set working directory, the full path must be given.

One can replace `bash` with any other shell that supports the same expected command language.

Comment: '--command="output.text"]...............Still got the same Error though the file exist in the working set directory ...................Error: Failed to execute child process "output.text" (No such file or directory).

Comment: Sir is s there any alternative to read from the .txt file and redirect it to the terminal??????

Comment: The `bash` is the important part.  It causes `bash` to read and execute the commands from the file. I repeated it three times in the answer.

Comment: sorry to mention it earlier comment.... i tried it with bash too.... still get the same error

Comment: I followed your suggestion and played a little with commands and it actually solved my problem thank you @Dan D.